# Custom javascript is not allowed to run on Salesforce DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, home-page-component, security-review, custom-link

Recently i have created an app which uses custom JavaScript in sidebar home page component using custom links, The app works perfectly and i also uploaded it to appexchange as managed released package and submitted it to review by salesforce.

Unfortunately review is negative saying Custom javascript is not allowed to run on Salesforce DOM. Below is details

> 1) Javascript in Salesforce DOM Vulnerability
>
> Notes
>
> Custom javascript is not allowed to run on Salesforce DOM.
>
> Please check the requirement checklist for more information
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist

Please guide how to resolve this.

```
**Custom Link Body:**
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/customjavascript')}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. OP has already followed the method outlined in the question/answer given to inject JS from sidebar. He is asking the new question "Now that I have injected JS from the sidebar, how do I pass security review?" I don't see a mention of security review in the question/answer to which the user has been directed.

Comment: Hi if this question is duplicate please post original link.

Comment: It's marked as a duplicate of "End of sidebar workarounds" which is linked at the top of the page. I don't think your question is a duplicate of that, but maybe you can ask it again, making even more clear that  you already know about sidebar injection through links, and now you want to know about Security Review.